# Vuejs: странное поведение при двустороннем связывании

Tags: vue.js

Пишу дататейбл. Структура таблицы, а именно необходимой для вопроса части, строится так:

1. `TableLayout` - главный, "верхний" слой таблицы, содержащий основные структуры данных. Обертка над `<table>`
2. `TableHead` - компонент, содержащий хеадер таблицы. Обертка над `<thead>`.
3. `TableHeadCell` - компонент, являющийся ячейкой хеадера таблицы, обертка над `<th>`.

Компонент `<v-table-body>` нам не интересен.

Идея состоит в том, чтоб в корне таблицы создавался массив параметров `columns`, необходимый для управления этой таблицей. Выглядит он вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно заметить, в этом массиве содержится 3 свойства, а именно:

1. `field` - ключ столбца;
2. `label` - выводимое название столбца;
3. `sorting` - состояние сортировки столбца.

Интересует нас `sorting`. Оно может принимать 3 значения: `none`, `asc`, `desc`. То есть это свойство показывает направление сортировки. Данный вопрос завязывается на изменении этого свойства.

Как видно, `columns` передается с модификатором `.sync` в дочерний компонент `<v-table-head>`. Он выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю, комментарии здесь не нужны. Всё и так предельно ясно. Перейдем сразу с компоненту ячейки таблицы. Выглядит он так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ничего сложного. Всё предельно ясно. Параметры `isSortAsc` и `isSortDesc` высчитываются в блоке `computed`. Я сознательно не стал включать их в картинку т.к. к вопросу они отношения не имеют. Свёрнутые if'ы в точности такие же как и развернутый. Отличается только второй параметр $emit'а. Проп имеет дефолтное значение и валидацию.

Структура ясна. Этот код отрабатывает хорошо, но не как задуманно. Ключевая проблема - это то, что при клике на ячейки хеадера, одновременно несколько параметров `sorting` могут принимать значение не `none`. То есть как бы сортировка происходит по нескольким столбцам. Задумано иначе. Сортировка должна происходить только по одному, а следовательно в массиве `columns` только один элемент должен иметь отличное от `none` свойство `sorting`. Значит при клике на `TableHeadCell` все значения `sorting` нужно сбрасывать. Конечно, кроме того, на который кликнули. Сделать это можно в родительском компоненте `TableHead`, отлавдивая событие и перебирая массив. Что ж, вот такой код получился:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И его поведение я никак не могу объяснить. К сожалению, не могу записать видео, поэтому объясню на словах. Если после обновления старицы кликнуть на любой `TableHeadCell`, то он будет отрабатывать как и задумано, как и в первой "версии" кода. Кликнуть можно сколько угодно - все хорошо. Но если кликнуть на любой другой элемент (условно "второй"), то произойдет интересная вещь. Все значения `sorting`, кроме нового, преобразуются к `none`. Ну, как оно и задумано. Новое значение тоже станет тем, каким и должно быть. Но если начать кликать на него повторно, то не произойдет ничего. Код как бы застывает. Никаких ошибок и предупреждений в консоли нет. Если же кликнуть на условно "третий" элемент, то не произойдет ничего. При этом если снова начать кликать на "первый" элемент, то он будет работать как нужно, меняя собственное значение, сбрасывая значения других. Это за гранью моего понимания. Скорее всего здесь что-то очевидное, но я закопался. Объясните, пожалуйста, что тут происходит и как привести мой код к рабочему состоянию.

`"vue": "^2.6.14"`

Answer (score 0):

В чем заключается проблема установить не удалось, однако решение найдено.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).